# Why passing Context every time when it's possible to get it using different methods

Tags: java, android, android-context

I'm new at Android...I was looking at source code of popular open source android apps like android mail,calendar... and noticed that in each `class,service,file...` always passing the `Context` parameter and the class initialise it to his local instance of `Context`, it almost appears in every class, many times.

My question is why those classes are need to get it as a parameter of their constructor or method while they can get it alone with those methods?

```
1. getApplicationContext()
2.  getContext()
3. getBaseContext()
```

They can set it in the start and use it...why so many methods in one class getting it? do they get other `Context` then those that they can get using on of the 3 methods above?
For example, I saw the `Service` is a subclass of a `Context class`, so he can basically use `this` keyword  and not wait for it from the caller.

Comment: you don't need to use  all those. Activity and service extend from context u so you can directly use `this`. a follow up read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context. Regarding constructor: constructor of which class?

Comment: each class that created have it's own constructor, and in the parameters one of them is the context for example `myClass (String firstName, String lastName, Context context) {this.context= context } `

Comment: is it a normal java class. if you need context there you need to pass it to the constructor. services activities no need for constructors. use `this`

Comment: Ok so why should I pass it if I can get it in any class with `getApplicationContext` and save passing unnecessary parameters?

Comment: read the link posted before. For some stuff you need Activity Context.

Comment: @AlexKulr a normal class does not have a `getApplicationContext` method. If it needs a `Context` it has to be passed in.